# Can't get DHT22 sensor to retry on failed read

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have written a short program to read the DHT22 using the new adafruit DHT library (using the Raspberry Pi 4). With this library the documentation suggests using the except RuntimeError since misreads are common. I want to achieve for the code to try another read on a failed one. I believe this code should do the trick but it only stays in the while loop until the first successful reading. If i unplug my sensor after that it just prints the last read value every two seconds. The code:

```
while True:
   t1 = None
   while t1 is None:
      try:
         t1 = device1.temperature
      except RuntimeError:
         pass 
   print("Device 1:", t1)
   time.sleep(2)
```

Result after i disconnect the sensor after last successful read:

```
Device 1: 27.0
Device 1: 27.0
Device 1: 27.0
Device 1: 27.0
Device 1: 27.0
Device 1: 27.0
...
```

Is there a core concept i am not getting? I am a beginner in Python...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the circuitpython adafruit DHT library's read temperature functions returns the last known value after an arror as long as a DHT device is open. I solved this by opening a dht device with adafruit_fht.DHT(pin) at the start of a try. This gives almost imediate retries after an error.

```
try:
   device1.dht.DHT22(pin)
   t1 = device1.temperature
except RuntimeError:
   time.sleep(.01)
   continue
```